# How to findout what a web page is waiting for

Tags: asp.net, performance, firebug

We are checking the performance of a web page with firebug.

Firebug reports "waiting" for a page for over 5 seconds, after which it took a 1 ms to recieve the page.

What does "waiting" mean in this context? How can it be reduced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, "waiting" indicates time taken form request issued to the first byte of response received. Time to receive is that total time to get all the page output. Waiting time can be larger due to slow network but in your case, it can be the case where server might be taking a long time to process the request. Correct way would be to profile at server end to see if issue was due to slower n/w or due to server side processing.

Comment: This would have been my answer if Vinay hadn't been faster, so I'm upvoting instead.